# My VLOOkup is not working and pops up an error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to VLookup an exact value, and if not found, go for a partial value (3 char. + * ie 111*).

Here's my Feuil1 :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG7q6.png

Here's my NewSheet :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIIdV.png

Here's my Sheet 3 :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Djyc.png

Add up : If it can look once it's done, for the values it has printed on Column C (only exact values here, no partial ones) and Vlookup Sheet 3 to print the Money too, it would be nice too :)

Here's the code I wrote, but I have an error...

````
Sub test()

Dim searchRange As Range

With Feuil1
    Dim last_y As Long
    last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set searchRange = .Range("A6:C" & last_y)
End With
  
With Worksheets("NewSheet")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
    Dim searchVal
    searchVal = .Cells(i, "A")
        
        Dim w_value As Variant
        If Not IsError(w_value) Then
        w_value = Application.VLookup(searchVal, searchRange, 3, False)
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = w_value
    
    Else
    
    Dim txtSplit
    Dim MidVal
    Dim v_value As Variant
        
        txtSplit = Mid(searchVal, 1, 3)
        MidVal = txtSplit & "~*"
        
        If Not IsError(w_value) Then
        v_value = Application.VLookup(MidVal, searchRange, 3, False)
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = w_value
        
    End If
    End If
    Next i
    
End With

End Sub```
````

Comment: `searcheRange` has an extra `e`

Comment: and if the vlookup does not find anything the return will be an error, so change: `If Not w_value Is Nothing Then` to `If Not IsError(w_value) Then`

Comment: `Option Explicit` needs to be at the top of the module to flag undeclared variables.

Comment: Edited the code a little, it doesn't find partial values (NA) and doesn't go down the list:/

Comment: Hi, maybe instead of vlookuping just use Range.find [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: Can you help out? I have no idea how Range.Find works...